# How to compare elements in each node and sum values if same in xsl for each loop

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, sum

I have a xml like below, which has multiple nodes. I have to loop through each node and see if other nodes have `wd:day_of_week` same then add all the `wd:calculated_quatity` for all those matched values.

For example for the below xml there are two `wd:day_of_week` values as 'Monday' , then we need to add the associated `wd:calculated_quantity` of those two as `4.75 + 4.08333`.

XML:

```
<wd:Time_Blocks_for_Worker>
            <wd:Day_of_the_Week>Monday</wd:Day_of_the_Week>
            <wd:Calendar_Date>2017-07-10-07:00</wd:Calendar_Date>
            <wd:Time_Type wd:Descriptor="Hours Worked">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da128ce5a1dc103f5656dad4dad70868</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Time_Code_Reference_ID">CA Hours Worked In/Out</wd:ID>
            </wd:Time_Type>
            <wd:Calculated_Quantity>4.75</wd:Calculated_Quantity>
        </wd:Time_Blocks_for_Worker>
        <wd:Time_Blocks_for_Worker>
            <wd:Day_of_the_Week>Monday</wd:Day_of_the_Week>
            <wd:Calendar_Date>2017-07-10-07:00</wd:Calendar_Date>
            <wd:Time_Type wd:Descriptor="Hours Worked">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da128ce5a1dc103f5656dad4dad70868</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Time_Code_Reference_ID">CA Hours Worked In/Out</wd:ID>
            </wd:Time_Type>
            <wd:Calculated_Quantity>4.083333</wd:Calculated_Quantity>
        </wd:Time_Blocks_for_Worker>
        <wd:Time_Blocks_for_Worker>
            <wd:Day_of_the_Week>Tuesday</wd:Day_of_the_Week>
            <wd:Calendar_Date>2017-07-11-07:00</wd:Calendar_Date>
            <wd:Time_Type wd:Descriptor="Hours Worked">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da128ce5a1dc103f5656dad4dad70868</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Time_Code_Reference_ID">CA Hours Worked In/Out</wd:ID>
            </wd:Time_Type>
            <wd:Calculated_Quantity>4.75</wd:Calculated_Quantity>
        </wd:Time_Blocks_for_Worker>
        <wd:Time_Blocks_for_Worker>
            <wd:Day_of_the_Week>Tuesday</wd:Day_of_the_Week>
            <wd:Calendar_Date>2017-07-11-07:00</wd:Calendar_Date>
            <wd:Time_Type wd:Descriptor="Hours Worked">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da128ce5a1dc103f5656dad4dad70868</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Time_Code_Reference_ID">CA Hours Worked In/Out</wd:ID>
            </wd:Time_Type>
            <wd:Calculated_Quantity>4.5</wd:Calculated_Quantity>
        </wd:Time_Blocks_for_Worker>
```

---

I am trying the XSL as below to loop through and compare.

```
<Calculated_Quantity>
            <xsl:for-each select="wd:Time_Blocks_for_Worker">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:if test="translate(wd:Day_of_the_Week, $smallcase, $uppercase) = wd:Day_of_the_Week">
                <xsl:when test="wd:Day_of_the_Week = wd:Day_of_the_Week">
                <xsl:value-of
                                            select="sum(wd:Time_Blocks_for_Worker/wd:Calculated_Quantity_1 | wd:Time_Blocks_for_Worker/wd:Calculated_Quantity)"/>
                </xsl:when>
             </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>    
       </Calculated_Quantity>
```

Comment: This is a *grouping* question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of examples with detailed explanation of **grouping** under XSLT tag on StackOverflow. Based on the XSLT version being used for transformation the answers are different for XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0.

The sample XML provided in the question has been used for transformation after removing the namespace prefix `wd:`. A sample output has been generated to demonstrate the use of **grouping**.

**XSLT 1.0**

A `<xsl:key>` has to be defined for grouping

```
<xsl:key name="weekday" match="Time_Blocks_for_Worker" use="Day_of_the_Week" />
```

Then match the templates that are similar to the defined key.

```
<xsl:template match="Time_Blocks_for_Worker[generate-id() = generate-id(key('weekday', Day_of_the_Week)[1])]">
```

Then the child nodes of the matched elements can be accessed and used as per the requirement. Below is the XSLT that produces a sample output calculating the sum of the hours worked on the weekday.

```
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="xsl"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:key name="weekday" match="Time_Blocks_for_Worker" use="Day_of_the_Week" />
    <xsl:template match="Time_Blocks_for_Worker[generate-id() = generate-id(key('weekday', Day_of_the_Week)[1])]">
        <xsl:variable name="timeBlock" select="key('weekday', Day_of_the_Week)" />
        <WeekDay>
            <Name>
                <xsl:value-of select="$timeBlock/Day_of_the_Week" />
            </Name>
            <Hours>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum($timeBlock/Calculated_Quantity)" />
            </Hours>
        </WeekDay>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Time_Blocks_for_Worker[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('weekday',Day_of_the_Week)[1]))]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This XSLT produces the sample output below

```
<WeekDay>
    <Name>Monday</Name>
    <Hours>8.833333</Hours>
</WeekDay>
<WeekDay>
    <Name>Tuesday</Name>
    <Hours>9.25</Hours>
</WeekDay>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

XSLT 2.0 provides an easier and compact solution for grouping by providing the `<xsl:for-each-group>` feature.

```
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="xsl"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Time_Blocks_for_Worker" group-by="Day_of_the_Week">
            <WeekDay>
                <Name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
                </Name>
                <Hours>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Calculated_Quantity)" />
                </Hours>
            </WeekDay>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This XSLT 2.0 also produces the same sample output as XSLT 1.0.